# Django queryset ordered by exisiting as OneToOne field in second model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to construct queryset based on relation between two models. Here is how they look:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']


class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo, related_name='bars')
    from_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['from_date']
```

Now I need queryset of `Foo` objects, but first I want to have objects which exist in `Bar` model, with Bar default ordering and then the rest of `Foo` objects with Foo ordering. Following return me a nice mess:

```
q = Foo.objects.all().order_by('bars','-date').distinct()
```

Also interesting thing is that I got different ordering in django1.5 and django1.6 for the queryset above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want Foo object that have a Bar object linked to them, that mean: filter.

```
Foo.objects.filter(bars__isnull=False)
```

But this will only be ordered by the default order of Foo date.
To have what you want you need to had the order_by at this queryset

```
Foo.objects.filter(bars__isnull=False).order_by('bars', '-date')
```

I wasn't sure about `order_by('bars'`) do. Does it order by the specific filed (from_date) or the id?

I tested with django 1.6 and the order_by was done on the right field (from_date), so may be django 1.5 does the order_by on the id and not the specific filed thus the different ordering?

You can force the filed to choose if you need to be comptable on both version or just for readibilty.

```
Foo.objects.filter(bars__isnull=False).order_by('bars__from_date', '-date')
```

*An other point*

Since your relationship is a OneToOne the `related_name` it shouldn't have a final s (bar instead of bars). This will clarify your code as django treat the OneToOne relationship a little different from the other relation.
Indeed if you have a `ForeignKey` relationship you will have to do that the get a (or all) Bar object:

```
foo = Foo.objects.get(id=1)
bars = foo.bars.all()
```

with a `OneToOne` you just have to do that:

```
foo = Foo.objects.get(id=1)
bar = foo.bar
```

The difference is due to the fact that a OneToOne relationship insure that a Foo object is linked to one and only one Bar object, with a ForeignKey relationship a Foo object can have one or MORE Bar object linked to it.

Comment: thanks but what I need is all ` Foo ` objects but listed as follow. Fist goes ones that exists in Bar model with Bar ordering and then the rest of the objects ordered by Foo ordering.

Comment: can't you do 2 request then? if you need the result in the same list use `itertools.chain`: `chain(Foo.objects.filter(bars__isnull=False).order_by('bars__from_date', '-date'), Foo.objects.filter(bars__isnull=True).all())`